# Syntax error, unexpected "$q"

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, syntax

I'm kinda new to the web development, so I don't know if I'm posting in the right place.
But I’ve started putting together a website.
But when I try to run this Query(see the Picture) I get the following message.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected "$q" (T_VARIABLE) in my
>   location

Do you have any idea what the problem could be?
I am trying to publish the Header of my table in MySQL to the content of my page. (I have no problem connecting or wring to my database.
But I seem to have a problem at line 6.

Thanks a lot!

[Lokk at line 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMLPS.jpg)

Comment: You are missing ; in line 1

Comment: share your code

Comment: include(); should ends with ";"

Comment: The backslashes here are wrong. If you want to use a Windows-style backslash you need to use `\\` a double backslash, not a single one, as there is a chance that the following character (depending on what it is) will turn the backslash-char into a control character. It is better to just use a forward slash on all platforms - this works on Windows as well.

Comment: I would guess you have a SQL injection vulnerability here too.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your code,

include statement in your code dont have `;`

```
include('config\setup.php');
```

Replace this line in your code and check.

Comment: Your most welcome mate !!

Answer (score 0):

try `";"` at end of every include statement **(OR php statement you are using)**

```
e.g.- 
<?php
include('config/setup.php'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP every line should be terminate by ';'
So whenever you are geting such kind of error just check your previous line. 
Here you are missing terminate at very 1st line.

```
include('config\setup.php');
```

Add this.